# PHP array push not working inside a function

Tags: php, reference

```
function add_member_data($id, $fname, $lname) {
$data = array(
    "ID" => $id,
    "First Name" => $fname,
    "Last Name" => $lname,
);

array_push($all_members, $data);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($data);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($all_members);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

i have this code but array push doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `$all_members` supposed to be a global variable? If so, you'll need to declare `global $all_members;` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

so there is a very limited amount of information here -
but to get this to work there needs to be access to the `$all_members` variable from within the function [and the function needs to be called].

here is an example of how I would do it:

```
$all_members = [
   ["ID" => 1, "Firsn Name" => "Edyth", "Last Name" => "Hammes"],
   ["ID" => 2, "Firsn Name" => "Maye", "Last Name" => "Gerhold"],
];

function add_member_data(&$all_members, $id, $fname, $lname) {
   $data = array(
      "ID" => $id,
      "First Name" => $fname,
      "Last Name" => $lname,
   );

   array_push($all_members, $data);

   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($data);
   echo "</pre>";

   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($all_members);
   echo "</pre>";
}

add_member_data($all_members, 3, "Jane", "Smith");
```